# Vertical and Horizontal Scrolling Website

Tags: html, css, scroll

I am working on a website (one pager) which is built after a cross. The vertical scroll works well and is solved with CSS (scroll-snap-type etc.) The problem is in the horizontal scroll and namely the problem is that if you scroll horizontally and then scroll vertically logically comes a blank page. How to solve this problem best (as explained in the sketch (arrow 1)) that the page info is called. Every "page" has a vh 100. The vertical Scroll is with vh 100 and vw200 (2 Pages)

EDIT: If you run the code snipped you can see, that if you use the horizontal slide the second slide is blocked if you scroll down. This is my Problem. I want to jump to the site infos / (subscription-container)

[image: illustration]

```css
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: white;
    
}

h1{
    font-weight: normal;
}


@font-face {
    font-family: 'besom_extendedregular';
    src: url('../src/webfonts/besom-extended-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('../src/webfonts/besom-extended-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}


.main-container{
    scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: 100vh;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;

}


.navi{
    position: fixed;

}

.hero{
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: beige;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    scroll-snap-align: start;

}

.logo-section{
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
    padding: 150px;
    /* height: 100vh; */
    


}

.logo-section img{
    /* position: absolute; */
    max-width: 70%;
    max-height: 270px;
       
}

.content-container{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 400vw;
    background-color: black;
    scroll-snap-align: start;
    flex-direction: row;
    display: flex;
    
    


}
.content-container .first{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 8em;
    background-color: brown;
    
}
.content-container .story{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 8em;
    background-color: red;
}



.subscription-container{
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: black;
    scroll-snap-align: start;
    padding-top: 80px;
    padding-left: 150px;
    padding-right: 150px;
    
}

.bottom-container{
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: black;
    scroll-snap-align: start;
    padding-top: 80px;


}

.footer-nav-main{
    float: left;
    display: flex;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-style: italic;
    margin-left: 35px;
    margin-right: 35px;
        
}

.footer-main{
    margin-top: 80vh;
}
```

```html
        <div class="main-container">



            <section class="hero">
                



                <div class="logo-section">
                    <img class="logo" src="" alt="Logo">
                </div>
                <div class="announcement-head">
                    <p>
                        Title
                    </p>
                </div>

                <div class="announcement-text">
                    <p>
                        Subtitle

                    </p>
                </div>



            </section>

            <div id="content-container" class="content-container">
                <section id="first" class="first">
                    <div>
                        <h1>First</h1>
                        <a href="#story">Story</a>
                    </div>
    
                    
    
    
                </section>
                <section id="story" class="story">
                    <div>
                        <h1>Story 1</h1>
                        <a href="#first">First</a>
                    </div>
    
                    
    
    
                </section>

                


            </div>


            <section class="subscription-container">
                <div class="main-head">
                    <h1>Dream with us !</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="main-text">
                    <p>
                        text section
                    </p>
                </div>

            </section>
            <section class="bottom-container">

                <div><h1>Bottom Container</h1></div>

                

                


                <div class="footer-main">
    
                    <ul class="footer-nav-main">
                        <li><a href="">Foot1</a></li>
                        <p>/</p>
                        <li><a href="">Foot2</a></li>
                        <p>/</p>
                        <li><a href="">Foot3</a></li>  
                      </ul>
                    <p class="bottom-text-copyright">© </p>
                
                </div>



            </section>


            



        </div>
```

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. See [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Please revise the snippet demo I created from your code to show the problem. It doesn't look like the image.

Answer (score 0):

to block horizontally scrolling you can use **overflow-y** css property.add this code into your css file:

```css
.body{
overflow-y: hidden;
overflow-x: auto;
}
```

this code automaticly removes horizontal scrool bar.